# Spring Data Repository finds unpersisted data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have really strange behavior with spring boot data and JPA with hibernate. Before my entity `CookbookRecipe` is even persisted it is found by the `CookBookRepository#findAll().`

```
public interface CookbookRecipeRepository extends ExtendedJpaRepository<CookbookRecipe, Long> {}
```

.

```
public class ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID> {
    // added a new helper method, but certainly not overridden findAll
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class CookbookRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    RecipeRepository recipeRepository;
    @Autowired
    CookbookRepository cookbookRepository;
    @Autowired
    CookbookRecipeRepository cookbookRecipeRepository;

    @Test
    public void WhenAddingSameAssociationAgain_ThenNoException() {
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.setTitle("A Recipe");
        recipe = recipeRepository.save(recipe);

        Cookbook cookbook = new Cookbook();
        cookbook.setTitle("A Cookbook");
        cookbook = cookbookRepository.save(cookbook);

        cookbook.addRecipe(recipe, "integrationtest", new Date());
        assertThat(cookbookRecipeRepository.findAll().size(), is(0));
        cookbook = cookbookRepository.save(cookbook);
        ...
    }
}
```

Cookbook Entity

```
public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe, String createdBy, Date createdDate) {
        final CookbookRecipe cookbookRecipe = new CookbookRecipe(this, recipe);
        cookbookRecipe.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
        cookbookRecipe.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
        if( !cookbookRecipes.contains(cookbookRecipe) && !recipe.getCookbookRecipes().contains(cookbookRecipe)) {
            cookbookRecipes.add(cookbookRecipe);
            recipe.getCookbookRecipes().add( cookbookRecipe );
        }
}
```

Please note the `assertThat(cookbookRecipeRepository.findAll().size(), is(0));` which fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <0>
     but: was <1>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no unpersisted data in your example. Triggering a query (for `findAll()`) causes the JPA persistence provider to flush all pending changes you made to a managed instance (`cookbook.addReceipe(…)`).

Besides that, if you have a repository for both `Recipe` and `Cookbook` it's very unlikely to have one a `CookbookRecipeRepository`, too. Make sure you think about where you aggregate boundaries are and only create repositories for aggregate roots.

Comment: Becase the `CookbookRecipe` Entity was added to a hibernate collection it becomes managed? This feels so side-effected. `CookbookRecipeRepository` is used in my tests for reading and verifying only.

Comment: "This feels so side-effected" you are not alone with that feeling, but this is how JPA works.

Comment: @Jens Schauder I accept this but it's annoying to go trough all of this "WTF?"-moments to understand how JPA/hibernate works.

Comment: A can feel your pain.